# Error: Field must be grouped or aggregated

Tags: soql, relationships

We have a lookup relationship between a custom object Problem__c and cases, one problem can be related to many cases. I am trying to query the field or problem records and the number of related cases, this is working partially by doing this.

```
select problem__r.name,count(casenumber) from case where problem__c!=null group by problem__r.name limit 10
```

The problem is that I need to get more fields from the problem object so I tried this

```
select problem__r.name,problem__r.status__c,count(casenumber) from case where problem__c!=null group by problem__r.name limit 10
```

But I get the error Error: Field must be grouped or aggregated Status__c. How can I retrieve more fields from the parent object using this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using aggregate functions like `count`, all other fields must be grouped. Try

```
select problem__r.name,problem__r.status__c,count(casenumber) 
from case where problem__c!=null 
group by problem__r.name, problem__r.status 
limit 10
```

Comment: This approach actually worked.

Comment: This helped me out to Mike!

Answer (score 4):

The real problem with your query is that you added `Count(fieldname)` to it. Per the [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) documentation:

> Note the following when using COUNT():
>
> ■COUNT() must be the only element in the SELECT list.
>
> ■You can use COUNT() with a LIMIT clause.
>
> ■You can't use COUNT() with an ORDER BY clause. Use COUNT(fieldName) instead.
>
> ■You can't use COUNT() with a GROUP BY clause for API version 19.0 and later. Use  COUNT(fieldName) instead.

Had you simply added the `problem__r.status__c` and `casenumber` fields you'd have been fine with adding those fields. If you wanted to get subtotals, you might want to consider using [GROUP By ROLLUP](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm). That would have allowed you to do something like this:

```
select problem__r.name,problem__r.status__c,count(casenumber) cnt from case where problem__c!=null GROUP BY ROLLUP (problem__r.name)  limit 10
```

BTW, `COUNT_DISTINCT(fieldname)` only returns non-null values. It might be worth playing with to see if using it would possibly help you change the syntax of your query to get the same results.

Comment: My T-SQL background has betrayed me; I wasn't aware of those restrictions on `count()`.

Comment: We all come from different backgrounds Mike. I've still lots to learn! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that the filter fields as well as the select fields need to be grouped by.

Works:

```
SELECT Vendor__c, COUNT(Id)vcaCount
FROM FFVendorCodeAssignment__c
GROUP BY Vendor__c, Status__c, Deleted__c
HAVING Status__c = 'Approved'
AND Deleted__c = FALSE
```

Fails:

```
SELECT Vendor__c, COUNT(Id)vcaCount
FROM FFVendorCodeAssignment__c
GROUP BY Vendor__c
HAVING Status__c = 'Approved'
AND Deleted__c = FALSE
```