# Error: Field must be grouped or aggregated - how do I join other fields?

Tags: soql

My question is slightly similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/error-field-must-be-grouped-or-aggregated) one:

I have a query that works fine:

```
select bank__r.id, min(processedDate__c)min from cashflow__c group by bank__r.id
```

and I want to add another field

```
select bank__r.name, bank__r.id, min(processedDate__c)min from cashflow__c group by bank__r.id
```

Idea there is to include the bank name associated with the most recent cash flow.  I know I could accomplish this with two queries, first one like the above and a second one like "select name from bank__c where id=:someId" but it seems like I should be able to get that other field included more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query already groups by a UID, then aggregating the name field won't matter. In other words, the min(bank__r.name) and max(bank__r.name) will be the same, since no matter how many aggregated rows are returned, for each id the name will be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That fixed it.  Sort of looks like a bug in SOQL that it should be required though.  Makes the intent of the query less obvious I think.